# Lipschitz condition absolute value

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Q1) Prove that the function $ F(X)=|X|$ is globally Lipschitz?

Q2) How to proof $F(X)=X^2$ is locally Lipschitz and not globally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q1) Note that $$||x|-|y||\leq |x-y|\qquad \forall x,y\in\Bbb R.$$

Q2) Note that
$$|x^2-y^2|\leq |x-y||x+y|\qquad \forall x,y\in\Bbb R,$$
and for any compact $\mathcal C\subset \mathbb R$ there exists $d>0$ such that $|x+y|\leq d$ for all $x,y\in \mathcal C$.

Comment: Thank you, but I need the full proof to show that the f(x)=|x| is globally Lipschitz.

Comment: You have all the elements to make the full proof ! And if you are not satisfy, have a look on the internet, but I want do the work for you !

Comment: I worked on the proof, but I could not get it. I also looked for the proof on the internet, but there is no complet the proof for f(x)=|x|.

Comment: If $||x|-|y||<|x-y|$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$ it's by definition globally Lipshitz !

Comment: If the f(x)=|x| is vector not scalar, can I apply the same inequality

Comment: Of course. If $N$ is a norm on $X$, you have the property that $|N(x)-N(y)|\leq N(x-y)$ for all $x,y\in X$. And thus all norm is Lipshitz on the normed space $(X,N(\cdot ))$

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the domain of both functions is $\mathbb{R}$, as you did not say anything about it.

**Hints:**

For Q1), write down what you have to show and see if it reminds you of an inequality that you should know.

For the "local"-part of Q2) use that the function is diffentiable and its derivative is continuous. For the "global"-part, write down what you have to show and try to simplify some expressions.